# How to return just data instead of html using jquery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following javascript code in my app.

```
        $.get("/readers/intotoid/number",function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

For that url, my rails app does:

```
def convert
    @book = Book.find(1)
    params[:integer]
end
```

When I display the alert, I just want params[:integer] to show.  Instad the entire html of the page /readers/intotoid/number displays.  I thought by returning params[:integer] in the convert method, data would be equal to that.  Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to the bottom of your convert method :

```
render :text => params[:integer], :layout => false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to return a Book as data.

Your convert method could return as json:

```
def convert
  @book = Book.find(1)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @book }
  end
end
```

So you need either ask your convert method inside your controller that you want a response as json:

```
$.get("/readers/intotoid/number.json",function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with rails but there should